# Save R randomForest object to SQL database

Tags: sql, r

Is there a way to save a randomForests object (or other large objects) from R into a SQL database.  The only thing I can think of is to dsub the object and save it as a varchar(max) but was wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native way is to serialize the object using `serialize()`. If your database supports binary objects, you can use the binary serialization, otherwise you can use `rawToChar(serialize(x, NULL, ascii=TRUE))` to obtain a string.

Note that `dput` is inherently dangerous for storage because it allows arbitrary execution attacks.